# Is Thread Kernel Object is CPU dependent

Tags: c#, multithreading, clr

I was going through a lecture by Jeffrey Ritcher regarding "Building responsive and scalable applications".

Here is the Youtube URL. 
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGSabgBo-S8]

I came across a statement that "Thread Kernel Object is the only CPU dependent DataStructure in OS not CPU agnostics".

Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: He probably means that its members are specific to which type of CPU is running (Intel, ARM, and so on).

Comment: He never actually says that.  And it is not the case, for example setting up the paging tables to provide memory-isolation for processes is very CPU-dependent.  He focuses on the CONTEXT implementation detail for threads only to point out why it is expensive.  And why you don't want to create too many threads, favor the threadpool and async I/O, the subject of the lecture.  A one hour session is not a substitute for a class or book about OS design.

Comment: @HansPassant what you recomend to read to understand in more detail

Comment: @HansPassant I understand what the whole lecture is all about, but can you please elaborate on what the statement exactly means?

"Thread Kernel Object is the only CPU dependent DataStructure in OS not CPU agnostics"